# Predicate Logic with Book Genres

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

I need to write each English language statement as a predicate expression.

S(x) is "x is a spy novel." L(x) is "x is long." M(x) is "x is a mystery." B(x,y) "x is better than y."

- Only mysteries are long.  -> how would i use predicate symbols to show "only?"
- Some spy novels are better than mysteries.  -> does this mean *all* mysteries?
- Spy novels are better than mysteries.  -> here I'm just unsure how to use the B(x,y) for better than
- Some mysteries are better than all spy novels.  -> how would I write a statement that uses "some" *and* "all?"

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

1) "Only mysteries are long" can be rewritten as : "There are no long things that are no mysteries".

Thus : $¬∃x(Long(x)∧¬Myst(x))$, i.e. :

> $∀x(Long(x) \to Myst(x))$.

---

2) Maybe; but if we read "Some spy novels are better than mysteries" to mean that **some** spy novels are better than **all** mysteries, than 2) is the same as 4) ...

Thus, I think that 2) and 3) must be formalized with free variables, like for 3) :

> $Spy(x) \land Myst(y) \land Bet(x,y)$.
>
> ---

4) "Some mysteries are better than all spy novels" is :

> $\exists x (Myst(x) \land \forall y (Spy(y) \to Bet(x,y))$.